# Find non-default ip address of router?

Tags: ip-address, router, ipconfig

I am trying to log into my router which was set up by the cable company. I have a new router which I am trying to apply the same settings to since it has a particular setup with our server.

It seems the IP address of the router was changed since I cannot get in with the standard 192.168.x.x.

An ipconfig gives an address of 169.254.233.38 and default gateway of 0.0.0.0
Apr -a gives 169.254.233.38 and 169.254.255.255

All I want to do is log onto the router without doing a reset. Any suggestions?

Not that it should matter, but its a belkin.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't connecting to the router's DHCP service at all. Addresses starting with 169.254 are self-assigned by clients when they can't get an assigned address. So there's no way to configure the router, because there's no route to it.

Is this a wired connection? Do the ports you're plugged in to have green status lights at each end? Try a different wired port on the router, or a different cable.

If it's a wireless connection and you are actually connecting with Wi-Fi, then it's probably something wrong with the router. Try cycling the power.

If none of this works, look up your specific router model number in a search engine, and find the manual. There will be instructions for resetting it to the factory default state, after which you should be able to connect to and configure it.

Comment: Figured it out by using angryip scanner and another router
q